# When scrolled to top of window, load results jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that when i click a button I call more results from my table, Im trying to get this to work when the button is 100px top of the window, however I cant seem to get it to work...

```
 $(function(){
  $('#showMore').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var number = $(".directory").children().length;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "getentries.php",
       data: "count="+number,
       success: function(results){
         $('.directory').append(results);
       }
     });

  });
```

});

So far ive tried

```
 $(function(){
  $('#showMore').offset(function(event) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery `.offset()` function is not for establishing an event handler. You're looking for `.scroll()`. In the event handler for "scroll" events, you can use `.offset()` to find out the current position.

I'll offer the caveat that browsers fire **a lot** of scroll events, so you may want to introduce a delay before doing any serious work in response to the user scrolling the window.